# Can't connect to Tor

Tags: configuration

I can't connect to Tor. Every time try to connect it gets stuck on loading network status and won't proceed any further. I used to connect just fine before but I tried to enter a socks5 proxy usin 127.0.0.1 and port 9150 and can't go back now. Below i have pasted the Tor log for you to see what it says:

```
19/09/2016 10:12:28.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
19/09/2016 10:12:28.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
19/09/2016 10:12:28.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
19/09/2016 10:12:28.600 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
19/09/2016 10:12:29.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
19/09/2016 10:12:29.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
19/09/2016 10:12:29.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
19/09/2016 10:12:29.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
19/09/2016 10:12:30.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
19/09/2016 10:12:51.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
19/09/2016 10:12:51.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
19/09/2016 10:12:51.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
19/09/2016 10:12:51.300 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
19/09/2016 10:13:04.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
19/09/2016 10:13:04.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
19/09/2016 10:13:04.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
19/09/2016 10:13:04.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
19/09/2016 10:13:13.300 [NOTICE] Bridge 'starman' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (0.0.2.0:3) based on the configured Bridge address. 
19/09/2016 10:13:13.300 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'starman' (fresh): $A2C13B7DFCAB1CBF3A884B6EB99A98067AB6EF44~starman at 0.0.2.0 
19/09/2016 10:13:13.300 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
19/09/2016 10:13:17.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
19/09/2016 10:13:17.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
19/09/2016 10:13:17.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
19/09/2016 10:13:17.300 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Any help given would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like just a slow connection to me? What happens if you let it run for longer than 1 minute?

Comment: Is your clock and time zone correct? Tor requires an accurate clock and an accurate time zone to work

Comment: it is forbidden for me to comment, so, I will add the answer. https://trisquel.info/en/forum/cant-get-tor-work#comment-100549 > I fixed the problem. It was my mistake. It was 9 am, but I use the 24
> hour format. So when changing the time I was always placing 9 instead
> of 21... Hahaha, so funny... anyway, yeah, that was the error, thank
> you! :)